# JavaFX8: How to tell when the mouse hovers over the header portion of a table column?

Tags: javafx, tableview, javafx-8, popover

I'd like to display a legend in a `PopOver` control when the user hovers the mouse over the 'header' portion of a particular `TableColumn`.  Is this possible?  How?  If not possible, I welcome suggestions for other approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install a tooltip on a node, so the trick is to get a node that is in the mouse neighbourhood of the column header.  There is a way to look it up using [Node.lookup](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Node.html#lookupAll-java.lang.String-) but it's not really ideal since something may change.

I think the simplest way is to set your own graphic for the header instead of the default text and add the tooltip to that.

```
    TableColumn<Data,String> tc1 = new TableColumn<>();
    TableColumn<Data,String> tc2 = new TableColumn<>();
    Tooltip t1 = new Tooltip("Column one");
    Tooltip t2 = new Tooltip("Column two");
    tc1.setGraphic(new Text("col 1"));
    tc2.setGraphic(new Label("col 2"));
    Tooltip.install(tc1.getGraphic(), t1);
    Tooltip.install(tc2.getGraphic(), t2);
```

Comment: another hack is to rely on internal (hopefully to be exposed soon) api and access the TableHeaderRow and its column header cells via table's skin (for an example see http://stackoverflow.com/a/30844357/203657)